# Where is the currently selected "Solution Configuration" option stored in VS 2010 or 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, configuration, build, automation

In VS 2010, or VS 2012, you can pick a "Solution Configuration", that has been custom defined, that can define local variables used with the `#if` `#elif` `#endif` syntax to change your code dynamically through that drop down. Also in that configuration, you can choose whether it's built or deployed, platform you're targeting, and the local configuration you want to use per project.

When you choose a configuration, then close Visual Studio, and re-open Visual Studio, it remembers what configuration you chose, what I can't seem to figure out, is where it saves/stores that configuration information, and I need to automate it.

Does anyone know of either:

- A way to use the command line compiler to automate solution level builds using solution configurations
- Where Visual Studio stores the currently selected configuration information
- Or, ideally, both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A way to use the command line compiler to automate solution level builds using solution configurations

```
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration="Solution Config" /p:Platform="Solution Platform"
```

For example, you can do:

```
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration="Release" YourSolution.sln
```

To build the "Release" configuration.

> Where Visual Studio stores the currently selected configuration information

This is stored in the user's `.suo` file, next to the `.sln` (solution) file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I swore I checked the suo file, but somehow, I missed it the first time!

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio actually stores a solution's build configuration selections in the solution file itself. Even though the "*.suo" file is not checked into version control, the solution's build configuration selections will propagate to other machines that are sync'ed to the same version control system.

If you open a "*.sln" file, you will see a section called "GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms)". If a project is not checked for build or deploy, you will see something like this:

> {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
> {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU

The ".0" strings indicate that the the build and deploy are unchecked.

Comment: In VS 2015 and 17 (i dont have older versions to test), the entire `Build.0` row will not be present when a project is not selected for building in that configuration